# CSS NavBar issue

Tags: html, css

I am making a css navbar dropdown, and am having some issues. I'm not the most experienced person in css, so a little help would be appreciated.

Here is the codepen which i created to show how it looks like now https://codepen.io/theproprogrammer188/pen/ZEXdVwO
Contrary to this even the hover effect's are missing in this case and implementing it is getting harder and harder for me. If anyone of you can solve my problem it would mean a lot to me thank you so much in advance

```css
header {
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding: 0px 30px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Get Started <img src="images/drop.svg" class="drop_icon" alt=""/></a>
            <ul class="submenu">
              <li>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/about.svg" alt="" />About Us</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/contact.svg" alt="" />Contact Us</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/dis.svg" alt="" />Disclaimer</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: please clarify your specific question instead of asking us to "solve your problem".

Comment: the problem is making the drop down V shape not sure how they managed to do that. So that was the reason of this question

Comment: can anyone please help me solve this issue i am really having a hard time figuring how to make this work

Answer (score 1):

> this will help you, which you want to achieve. a triangle dropdown

```css
nav {
  background-color: black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul,
nav li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}

nav>ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav>ul>li {
  position: relative;
}

nav>ul>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

nav>ul>li>ul {
  display: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  padding-top: 15px;
}

nav>ul>li>ul>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid darkgray;
}

nav>ul>li>ul:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: 5px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  content: '';
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid black;
}

nav>ul>li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Dropdown1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Option1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option2 A Long One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Dropdown2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Option1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Dropdown3</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Option1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Mirza it really helped

Comment: can you share me your telegram or discord or email where i can reach you?